# Hyper-V how to connect to VM guest via tcp from host

Tags: networking, centos, windows-10, hyper-v

Premise: I'm a developer, not a sysdamin or something similar, so please be patient! :)

A more serius premise: my host machine is a Windows 10 notebook, connected via LAN to the company network.

**What I need**

I need to test a MongoDB instance in a CentOS VM created with Hyper-V.

**What I did**

First I created an external network adapter in order to allow Internet connection to the guest, retrieve updated packages and install all the software needed.

It worked nicely and in few minutes my VM was ready.

Then I tried to connect with a mongodb client (Compass) **FROM THE HOST**, but obviously it did not worked.

**NOTE**
I can connect to mongo directly from the guest machine (so mongo is up and running).
I ensured that mongo could be reachable from outside, setting bindIP=0.0.0.0 and configured SELinux (not so sure about this, I'm not so confident with linux configurations, specially with RedHat-like distros)

```
sudo semanage port -a -t mongod_port_t -p tcp 27017
```

I googled a lot, facing with NAT and other fancy networking stuff I'm not accostumed to, but without results.
Now,I know that at least I need an internal network, but even so, I cannot connect to the guest VM via Compass.

I don't understand what I am missing.

Comment: Ehi dude, why downvote this question without adding nothing?
I searched on the web for 2 days and I did a lot of tests before post the question.
Is there a REAL reason to downvote  the question or you are just a toxic user?

Comment: some parts are unclear here.  
_Is the mongodb client in your Centos7 VM?  

_"From the host" = from your windows 10 machine which doesn't run hyperV?  

_Where is the hyperV?

_ Can you ping the centos7 vm from the host? Can you do a traceroute? Do you have a default gateway? (ipconfig /all)

_ When you try to ping the centos7 vm, can you run "tcpdump icmp" and see if you see packets coming the Windows10 machine.

_ Can you ping from the centos7vm to the Windows10 machine?    

It is probably a routing issue. Could also be related to port/ip blocked on the centosvm

Comment: 1) >>some parts are unclear here. _Is the mongodb client in your Centos7 VM?

Yes, it is.

2) >> _"From the host" = from your windows 10 machine which doesn't run hyperV? _Where is the hyperV?

I wrote: my host machine is a Windows 10 notebook, connected via LAN to the company network.

I don't understand what is the unclear part here. 
In the virtualization context, usually, the HOST is the machine running the virtualization software, so

>> _Where is the hyperV? _ 

On my Windows 10 notebook. Hope this time is more clear.